# Android Broken eth0 Socket - Replace with USB eth1

Tags: android, usb, ethernet

The Android 4.4 device (radxa rock) in question has a broken ethernet socket due to forcing a slightly oversized plug in it.

Im replacement I have a Usb-ethernet dongle connected fairy successfully - using adb I can do stuff like:

```
netcfg eth0 down
netcfg eth1 up
netcfg eth1 dhcp
setprop dhcp.eth1.dns1 8.8.8.8
netcfg                                                     
lo       UP127.0.0.1/8   0x00000049 00:00:00:00:00:00
eth0     DOWN            0.0.0.0/0   0x00001002 6e:47:fe:70:62:00
sit0     DOWN            0.0.0.0/0   0x00000080 00:00:00:00:00:00
ip6tnl0  DOWN            0.0.0.0/0   0x00000080 00:00:00:00:00:00
eth1     UP              192.168.1.101/24  0x00001043 00:0e:c6:c3:4b:2d
```

After this I can ping my local network from an adb shell:

```
ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.51 ms
```

But external pings fail.

```
ping www.google.com  
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

My question is how can I get the ethernet interface recognised in the Android 4.4 Setup app? What I see there is no IP address or other parameter populated.

Ideally I would like to disable the on-board eth0 hardware.

Thanks